# Oracle plsql, select in another select

Tags: regex, oracle, select, plsql

I have 2 selects;
I need to use select in another.

1. main select:

```
SELECT home_id, home_type, bathrooms, comment, regexp_substr(comment, '[0-9]{20}', 1, 1) acc,
FROM homes
WHERE home_id < 500
AND home_type = 'two-storey'
```

2. 

```
 SELECT distinct l.acc_n,l.gl_id,l.ct FROM sdogl l WHERE l.acc_n='12345678901111472601'
```

At the end I need to take something like this:

```
SELECT h.home_id, h.home_type, h.bathrooms, h.comment, regexp_substr(h.comment, '[0-9]{20}', 1, 1) acc, l.acc_n,l.gl_id,l.ct
FROM homes h, sdogl l
WHERE home_id < 500
**AND 'result regexp'=l.acc_n**
AND home_type = 'two-storey'
```

Thank you for your attention!

I tried to put

```
l.acc_n in (SELECT distinct l.acc_n FROM sdogl l)
```

It did not help

Comment: Did you try putting your regexp_substr expression in your WHERE clause for the join?

Comment: Also do not use this old style joins (tables separated by comma in the FROM section), use the proper SQL Ansi style `inner join` in the from section.

Comment: An as Paul comment: `**AND 'result regexp'=l.acc_n**` for this `and regexp_substr(comment, '[0-9]{20}', 1, 1) = l.acc_n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression in the join condition:

```sql
SELECT h.home_id,
       h.home_type,
       h.bathrooms,
       h.comment,
       regexp_substr(h.comment, '[0-9]{20}', 1, 1) acc,
       l.acc_n,
       l.gl_id,
       l.ct
FROM   homes h
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT distinct
                acc_n,
                gl_id,
                ct
         FROM   sdogl
         WHERE  acc_n='12345678901111472601'
       ) l
       ON regexp_substr(h.comment, '[0-9]{20}', 1, 1) = l.acc_n
WHERE  home_id < 500
AND    home_type = 'two-storey'
```